# How to recover checked and not checkboxes depending of a row values 1,2,5,6

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

i have a table with a column called "roles" indicating roles of persons in this way "1,3,6.." and other table with this roles names. Any id coincides with a role.

i'm trying to print all roles as checkboxes and checked if the person has any of these roles.

i was trying with implode and explode without result, Can you guide me?

```
<input type="checkbox" name="roles[]" value="'.($row['id']).'" >'.($row['name']).'</input>
```

Comment: Where is the loop around this part of code? Are you using any templating engine like twig or anything? The implode/explode-part must be around that line of code and that's what you are asking for, right? Please provide the surrounding code so people on SO can help you.

Comment: hi fuzz, the point is i was trying different things but nothing works.. i want to know what the best way to make it

Comment: I understand but to answer that question one needs to know how you create your templates that will be returned. Of course one can use a loop that walks through an array after exploding your "roles". So are you saying in your $row-Array there is another column besides name and id that contains a string like "1,3,6,..." or is $row one row of the "other" table? Maybe you could give an example of a dataset that you try to display (in a table or like).

Comment: there are two tables, one is "persons" and another "roles", persons has a lot of columns with characteristics, one of this columns is "roles_ids", inside there are the person roles saved in this way "1,4,7,8..." any person has different roles of course.  "Roles" table has only the id and name columns. there is not tables between them. what the best way to make the loop and obtain checkboxes checked in case this rol exist in the persons table.

Comment: You should save `1` in its own row, `4` in its own row, etc.. Not a list in one row.

Comment: do you mean is impossible in my way?

Comment: something like this http://jsfiddle.net/WFXun/

Comment: My approach would be like the one from @Windy Since you want one checkbox per role, you need to walk through each role anyway. In combination with this it would be best to have a ManyToMany Table though (user_id <--> role_id), since it makes querying for roles a lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    $user_id = $_REQUEST['user_id'];
    $user_role = array();
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT role_id FROM user_role where user_id = '$user_id' ");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_BOTH)) {
            $user_role[] = explode(',' $row['role_id']);
    }// end while

    $getRoleList = mysql_query("select role_id, role_name from role ");
    while ($roleRow = mysql_fetch_array($getRoleList, MYSQL_BOTH)) {
                if(in_array($roleRow['role_id'], $user_role)){
                    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="roles[]" value="'.($roleRow['role_id']).'" checked="checked">'.($roleRow['role_name']);
                }else{
                    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="roles[]" value="'.($roleRow['role_id']).'" >'.($roleRow['role_name']);
                }// end if  
    }// end while
```